# How can I run my own ios app on my iphone 6S with iOs 10.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I developed an app with XCode 8. However, I don't really find any help how to run my app on my own phone. There are just some tutorials for running it on my phone with XCode 7 but those don't really work for me. 
Does somebody know how to do that ? Thank you !

Comment: What have you tried ? What problems are you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://developer.apple.com and log in with your Apple developer account.
2. Create a developer certificate
3. Create an app id for your app
4. Create a provisioning profile
5. Download the provisioning profile and import it into Xcode.
6. Connect your iPhone to your computer.  Select your iPhone in Xcode.
7. Build and run your app.

Or let Xcode do all that for you, since it happens automatically if Xcode is connected to your developer account.

This process is all documented on Apple's developer web site.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you just need to:

- Start Xcode
- Unlock your iPhone
- Connect your iPhone to your mac using the Lightning USB cable.

You should be asked (by Xcode) if you want to use the connected phone as a development device.

You can check, if the device is know to Xcode by clicking on `Window / Devices`. If you connect a device for the first time a little bit of 'magic' is going on that takes a while to complete.

Something like this maybe shown add 'Devices': [image: Busy]